# Unable to load data from NSUserDefaults when trying to display contents of table in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have an iOS app that stores two `NSMutableArray`'s as objects in `NSUserDefaults` in the event that there is no WiFi or Data connectivity.  On a subsequent visit, the user should be able to load the stored data in their table by retrieving the saved data from `NSUserDefaults`, but unfortunately I am unable to do so.  The `NSMutableArrays` are storing objects that hold various `NSString` values as parameters.

Here is the code that saves my data in my Singleton class:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[DataModel sharedInstance].testResultList forKey:@"resultTable"];
    [defaults setObject:[DataModel sharedInstance].testResults forKey:@"jsonTable"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

and here is the code from `UITableView` class which is supposed to retrieve the data and load them into a table:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([[DataModel sharedInstance].testResults count] == 0) {

        if ([defaults objectForKey:@"resultTable"] == nil) {

            return;
        }

        else {

            [DataModel sharedInstance].testResultList = [defaults objectForKey:@"resultTable"];
            [DataModel sharedInstance].testResults = [defaults objectForKey:@"jsonTable"];


        }


    }


}
```

and here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"testresultcell";
    ResultTableViewCell *cell = (ResultTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ResultTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    TestResult *tResult = [[DataModel sharedInstance].testResultList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.name.text = tResult.testTitle;
    cell.date.text = tResult.dateStamp;
    cell.score.text = [[DataModel sharedInstance] getScore:tResult.score];
    cell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[DataModel sharedInstance] getImg:tResult.score]];

    return cell;
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?  I am initially checking to see if the current value of the `NSMutableArray`'s are empty.  It is only then do I go and check to see if a saved copy of the `NSMutableArray` exists.  If so, then I need to load the array and display the contents in my table.

Comment: Trace through the execution with the Xcode debugger and/or go caveman with NSLog()s.

Comment: Look at `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to handle your classes in your NSDictionary.

Comment: For archiving, examples:
`NSData *archiveData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:rootObject];`
`NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archiveData];`

Implement these methods in the c=lass to be archived/unarchived:
`- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder`
`- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical pattern for doing that is as follows (I usually do it in my ApplicationDelegate):

```
// Set up some default values
NSDictionary *myDefaults = @{@"aStringDefaultKey":@"someString",@"aBoolKey":@YES};

// Register the default values
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:myDefaults];

// Get a reference to them
NSUserDefaults *userSettings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

I don't see where you registered your default values with NSUserDefaults. If you don't do that they will not be supplied as default values in the absence of a previously set value.

Then later you can reference the value or set the value using something like:

```
// Set a value or update a value
[userSettings setObject:@"anotherString" forKey:@"aStringDefaultKey"];
[userSettings objectForKey:@"aStringDefaultKey"];
```

**EDIT:** And if it turns out that your DataModel Object (which you didn't post any code for) cannot be stored because it does not conform to NSCopy rules, then serialize it into an NSData Object which CAN be stored in an NSDictionary, and do it that way.

Comment: Whose to say what is typical in iOS. We use it in our Apps like that every day :) and I never wrote a line of OSX code in my life....but have written quite a few iOS apps.

Comment: From Apple's documentation: "The contents of the registration domain are not written to disk" so that probably is not what is needed here. The values do not persist across launches. From the question it seems the OP wants the values to persist. Note the OP wrote: "load the stored data". The OP never wrote he wanted "default values", just that he is using `NSUserDefaults`. Nor did the OP even mention Registering them in the appDelegate.

Comment: Then why is he using [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]... that is sort of the point of that. And since you like to repeat yourself, I will as well... if you Register them in the appDelegate, you DO NOT NEED to persist them because they are persisted in your code.

Comment: I want to thank both of you for trying to help me, but I think the problem is that I am trying to store objects that can NOT be represented in a property list.  I am trying to store two NSMutableDictionary's that are holding custom objects, and not a single value.  It is because of this I believe I am having issues.  Can you suggest a possible workaround?

Comment: Convert them to an object that CAN be stored in an NSDictionary. What exactly are you trying to store? Can't really tell from your example. Most things can be converted to NSNumber or NSString which can be placed into NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I am trying to store two NSMutableArray's, both of which hold custom objects that have multiple parameters.

Comment: Well can you convert the custom objects to something like a properties list? If you can, then you can store it in an NSDictionary.

Comment: If you can serialize the Custom Object into an NSData object, then you can store that in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: In the array, I have about twenty objects, each object having 4 NSString parameters.  I apologize for my ignorance, but what exactly do you mean by serialize?  As I save these objects, I need to be able to retrieve these objects later, and then re-save them in future sessions.

Comment: Post the structure of the object your trying to save. I cant help much without knowing what exactly it contains. If it is an NSArray with NSStrings in it, then it DOES conform to NSCopy rules and you SHOULD be able to save it in user defaults... and then your earlier assertion that it can't be saved is not correct and the problem is something else.

Comment: @Cliff, thanks for your comment on serializing the object to an NSData object which can then be stored in NSUserDefaults.  That is exactly what I had to do to make it work.  Can you please post an answer with that solution, or modify your solution to include so that I can accept your answer?